# NTRIP RTCM 3.0 -3.1

Tags: trimble

I have a Trimble Geoxplorer XH 2008 that supports RTCM 3.0, with which I have tried to obtain corrections via NTRIP of a base that emits in RTCM 3.1 I have not been able to obtain these corrections and I wonder if the reason is for the protocol difference (RTCM 3.1 and RTCM 3.0) between the sending base and the receiving equipment.

Any light on the possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

You are right about RTCM format being the problem.  According to the Geo2008 XH Datasheet, Geo2008 only supports RTCM 2.x, RTCM 3.0, CMR and CMR+.  Support for RTCM 3.1 was introduced with Geo6000.  I don't know of any practical way of using RTCM 3.1 or later on a Geo2008.